# Gamma distribution parameters Python

Tags: python, distribution, gamma

I am trying to find the shape and scale parameters for the gamma distribution of some data, but I was not able to find a method to work this out.

How do you commonly do it? I am analyzing response times and they look like this:

```
RT (ms)
647.6187042
598.4195305
503.0288826
551.2494272
519.6577653
487.8137089
951.4768826
615.0730516
[many more similar data deleted]
```

Should I use MatLab for this instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fitting a gamma distribution with (python) Scipy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896179/fitting-a-gamma-distribution-with-python-scipy)

Comment: I looked at the post mentioned but I am trying to find a similar way to the one done in MatLab where you use the function GamFit. Is there a corresponding function for Python?

Comment: @CatM Sure, right in the reference - you great object of the type `gamma` and call `fit()` method

Comment: I tried that method before asking the question and it failed to produce valid results, the mean was too low (a little more than one hundred milliseconds).

Comment: Well, there is momentum method as well - compute mean, variance and solve equations for alpha and beta

Comment: Could you provide more data, so fit could be tested?

Comment: I used that method before and the values were considerably different from the ones I obtained in MatLab.