# Fit Gamma Distribution

Tags: python, matplotlib, statistics

I have the following problem for my homework. So far, I have calculated the average and standard deviation, created a histogram for the averages and the density fit. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to solve the problem regarding the gamma distribution. How can I fit the Gamma distribution to the histogram? I am new to Python and appreciate all kind of support.

P.S. we are working with logreturns of S&P stocks.

```
Compute the averages and standard deviations for each stock. Properly treat any missing values. Plot a frequency histogram for the averages with a density fit. Add a fit based on normal distribution. Do the same for the standard deviations, but
use a fit to gamma distribution.
```

Comment: Here you are [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896179/fitting-a-gamma-distribution-with-python-scipy]

Comment: Thanks a lot, dave! And sorry that I could not find the answer by myself!